# How to check if the trading session is open or closed in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

Please, how to check in TradingView's **Pine Script version 4** if the market or session is closed or not?

Part of my script needs to check when (`TVC:DXY`) trading session is open for trading or closed.

My objective is merely to create a boolean variable that checks if the market is active or not. I believe there should be a built-in variable that checks if the session is currently active or not for a given ticker (in my specific case, it is the TVC:DXY).

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `barstate.isrealtime` answers your question.

Comment: `barstate.isrealtime` will only be `true` on the last bar (if the market is open). It will be `false` in all other cases. See [Bar states](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Bar_states_Built-in_variables_barstate.html?highlight=isrealtime) in the user manual.