# Check whether the market is open without using the 'barstate.isrealtime' variable (in Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script

How can I check whether the market is open or closed before reaching the last bar?

This [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678549/how-to-check-if-the-trading-session-is-open-or-closed-in-pine-script) suggests using the `barstate.isrealtime` built-in variable for that, but this will turn `true` only at the end of the script run (at the last bar of the chart). I need to know the status of the market before that.

Sure, I could write a function that will check the trading hours with the current hour. But I am looking for a solution that will work for all TradingView stock exchanges (with various schedules, time frames, holidays, etc), not just one or two exchanges.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
session.ismarket
```

Returns true if the current bar is a part of the regular trading hours (i.e. market hours), false otherwise
See : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session{dot}ismarket](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Dismarket)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not helpful at all. On daily, weekly and monthly timeframes, `session.ismarket` will always return `true`, so this variable is only useful for intraday timeframes (check [this article](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Sessions.html)). Plus, I believe it relates to the state of the market at the time of each past bar, not to the present status of the market.